# Unable to use "using namespace Microsoft::Win32" in visual studio 2010 c++ file,help me out

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I'm u unable to use  the following namespace "using namespace Microsoft::Win32"; in visual studio 2010.Actually I'm trying to access the system registry using this command.Whenever,I type this command i end up getting something like "name followed by :: must be a class or namespace name" .Help me out below mentioned is my code.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<Windows.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
    #define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383
    using namespace Microsoft::Win32;
```

Comment: does `namespace Microsoft{ namespace Win32{ ... } }` even exist?

Comment: There's no such namespace defined in any of the headers you are including, hence the error. This `Microsoft::Win32` business seems like CLI stuff to me.

Comment: Yes,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df4afx57(v=vs.90).aspx u can check this out!

Comment: That's C++/CLI. Read the page more carefully.

Comment: yes..which means cannot i use it in c++?

Comment: You can - you just need to, at minimum, compile your program with `/clr`. Read the page you linked to. The code has a comment that explains.

Comment: It might be C++/CX you're after rather than C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft examples on msdn.microsoft.com, there is such a namespace and their C++ examples use:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Security::Permissions;
using namespace Microsoft::Win32;
```

You might also need to set your project to include the relevant Assembly, which is mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll).

Per comment by Creris below, apparently this also requires the CLR compiler option /clr.

(Oh, and sorry for posting the C# reference to Microsoft.Win32)

Comment: such namespace only exists in C++/CLI, so you have to compile with /clr to use it. Note: I didn't downvote you

Comment: I wnat to creat  "Registry::CreateRegister( std::string path)" something like this, Which i couldnot do ..help me out

Comment: Ok, that's a different question, but have you tried RegCreateKeyEx ? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875

Comment: So... is there something inaccurate about this version of this answer, which I can improve? Or do anonymous downvotes just have a gravitational pull?